# How to make a KornShell script to go to new line

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ksh

How can I make a KornShell (ksh) script go to new line when I am typing in the terminal? It is currently going to the end of the current line.

Comment: LOL. That was my first thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the multiline option:

```
set -o multiline
```

Comment: this doesn't work. Nothing happens when I reach the end of the current line it doesn't go on the next. Anything else?

Comment: It may be a terminal settings problem instead of a shell problem then. if you run `cat > /dev/null` and type past the end of the line, what happens then?

Comment: well it goes to another line when I reach the end of the current. So how can I change settings of the terminal